# Is there any way to easily revert apt-get upgrades to previous 'snapshot'

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade

Is there a way to easily revert to an apt-get upgrade?  I want to be able to run a snapshot to a known working baseline, then let let upgrades run.  If a fault is detected I want to be able to revert that update either temporary or permemently.  Can this be done with Apt tools?  If not is there an OverlayFS or LVM based solution for this.

Comment: btrfs: https://www.linux.com/learn/how-create-and-manage-btrfs-snapshots-and-rollbacks-linux-part-2

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [a rollback mechanism](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79050/can-i-rollback-an-apt-get-upgrade-if-something-goes-wrong) will help you.

Alternatively you may consider taking a snapshot via lvm since its much easier and less hacky.